# Lua, nmap, sqlite3 and ubuntu - module 'luasql.sqlite3' not found

Tags: ubuntu, sqlite, lua, installation, nmap

I need to work with nmap and sqlite3 and I installed lua 5.1 and lua-sql-sqlite3 on an ubuntu machine:

```
sudo apt-get install lua5.1; sudo apt-get install lua-sql-sqlite3
```

Now, when I'm doing this:

```
$ lua
Lua 5.2.1  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> drv = require "luasql.sqlite3"
> print(drv._VERSION)
LuaSQL 2.3.0
```

Everything is okay, but when I'm trying to run nmap nse scrint with this line:

```
require "luasql.sqlite3"
```

I'm using this nse script [sqlite-output.nse](https://github.com/exitnode/nmap-sqlite-output)  for working with nmap and sqlite3.

I have the error:

```
$ sudo nmap --script=sqlite-output.nse localhost
[sudo] password for alex: 

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-03-13 04:16 EET
NSE: Failed to load sqlite-output.nse:
sqlite-output.nse:7: module 'luasql.sqlite3' not found:
    NSE failed to find nselib/luasql/sqlite3.lua in search paths.
    no field package.preload['luasql.sqlite3']
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/luasql/sqlite3.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/luasql/sqlite3/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/luasql/sqlite3.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/luasql/sqlite3/init.lua'
    no file './luasql/sqlite3.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/luasql/sqlite3.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so'
    no file './luasql/sqlite3.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/luasql.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so'
    no file './luasql.so'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    sqlite-output.nse:7: in function <sqlite-output.nse:1>
NSE: failed to initialize the script engine:
/usr/local/bin/../share/nmap/nse_main.lua:600: could not load script
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    /usr/local/bin/../share/nmap/nse_main.lua:600: in function 'new'
    /usr/local/bin/../share/nmap/nse_main.lua:805: in function 'get_chosen_scripts'
    /usr/local/bin/../share/nmap/nse_main.lua:1249: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

Answer (score 3):

when you search for "luasql" in your filesystem, where is it installed? On my machine it looks like this:

```
micha@squeak:~$ sudo find / -name luasql
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.2/luasql
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.1/luasql
```

Is nmap installed from the Ubuntu repo or is it self compiled?

Edit: If your lua libs are not inside the search paths of nmap you can create a softlink like this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua /usr/local/lib/lua
```